# Mobile Safari crashes (low memory)

Tags: google-maps, safari, crash, transform

I've encountered a problem, that mobile safari on both iPad and iPhone crashes after our [site](http://itera.no/) is loaded.
Different suggestions found here didn't lead to any solution. Here are things I've tried:

- Removing -webkit-transition elements
- Removing custom fonts
- Turning off orientationchange events
- Turning off google maps
- Turning off masonry plugin

Applying all of them at the same time didn't help either - when switching orientation to horizontal on [Investor Relations](http://www.itera.no/Investor-relations/) page, Safari crashes, though there are not to much scripts and data on this page. Another guys, who were investigating this issue earlier, have found that tables could cause that. But, considering that browser crashes even on pages without tables...

So I'm run out of ideas here. Maybe somebody have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I refuse to call it a fix... No-one on the web seems to know for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You should also look at your use of animations and absolute / fixed positioning: each of those CSS attributes will create a new stacking context, which causes Mobile Safari to create a separate layer for an element. Search for "stacking context" and you'll find a number of features create new layers:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html

Layers are often good for performance but they require memory. After you [enable Web Inspector for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH2-SW8) you can open the Web Inspector and use the Layers sidebar to see each separate layer and its memory consumption. Your site currently takes something like 50+MB on an iPhone 4S, which is definitely heading into crash territory.

The best way to avoid this is not to create DOM elements at all for features which aren't visible but you might also be able to avoid the expensive effects by setting them on the class which toggles makes the element visible, setting `visibility: hidden` and toggling it in JavaScript, etc.